Python Usage of del with OOP and Objects
Dear StackOverflow community. I have a problem in Python. I created a very basic class named Customer with basic methods to simulate real-life customers. However, I encountered an issue. I defined a class method called remove_customer, and I used the *del *keyword inside it. But I observed that my function does not remove the object belonging to the Customer class. I tried taking out the del keyword and putting outside of class , and I noticed that these two approaches yielded different results. I can't figure out why this happened. Can someone clarify the situation I encountered?
note:
I have consulted my teacher but he replied me it is a bad practice using OOP and del like this way.
class Customer():
    customer_list=[]
    __slots__=["name","age","gender"]
    def __init__(self,name:str,age:int,gender:int):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.gender=gender
        Customer.add_customer(self)
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_age(self):
        return self.age
    def get_gender(self):
        return self.gender
    @classmethod
    def add_customer(cls,customer):
        cls.customer_list.append(customer)


if __name__=="__main__":
    customer1=Customer("Jack",28,1)
    customer2=Customer("Julia",27,0)
    for x in Customer.customer_list:
        print(x.name)
    Customer.customer_list.remove(customer1)
    del customer1
    print(customer1)

class Customer():
    customer_list=[]
    __slots__=["name","age","gender"]
    def __init__(self,name:str,age:int,gender:int):
        self.name=name
        self.age=age
        self.gender=gender
        Customer.add_customer(self)
    def get_name(self):
        return self.name
    def get_age(self):
        return self.age
    def get_gender(self):
        return self.gender
    @classmethod
    def add_customer(cls,customer):
        cls.customer_list.append(customer)
    @classmethod
    def remove_customer(cls,customer):
        cls.customer_list.remove(customer)
        del customer


if __name__=="__main__":
    customer1=Customer("Jack",28,1)
    customer2=Customer("Julia",27,0)
    for x in Customer.customer_list:
        print(x.name)
    Customer.remove_customer(customer1)
    print(customer1)

first one yields output :
NameError: name 'customer1' is not defined. Did you mean: 'customer2'?
But second one yields different output even doing same thing (I only modified place of del) :
Jack
Julia
<main.Customer object at 0x0000026DD3D76D00>

That del customer line inside .remove_customer() is completely pointless.  All it does is remove a local variable, that would disappear anyway when the method returns.  It has no effect whatsoever on the global variable customer1, even though that's where the value of the local variable came from.

Allow Python to do the garbage collection for you unless you have a special case (e.g., a very large object of some kind that you only want to "live" briefly). Even then you'd need to be sure that there are no active references to the object you're deleting
